# Expressing ΔH and ΔS using heat capacities and then using these to express ΔG

Tags: thermodynamics

Essentially, I think I derived the correct expressions for ΔH and ΔS, but for some reason I can't combine them into the correct form of ΔG.

Workings below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta G(T_1) = \Delta H(T_1) - T_1 \Delta S(T_1)$$

$$\Delta G(T_2) = \Delta H(T_2) - T_2 \Delta S(T_2)$$

$$\Delta G(T_2) - \Delta G(T_1) = \Delta H(T_2) - \Delta H(T_1) + T_1 \Delta S(T_1) - T_2 \Delta S(T_2) = \\
\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\Delta C_\mathrm{p}(T)\mathrm{d}T} +  T_1 \Delta S(T_1) - T_2 \left(\Delta S(T_1)+\int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\frac{\Delta C_\mathrm{p}(T)}{T}\mathrm{d}T}\right) = \\ \int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\Delta C_\mathrm{p}(T)\mathrm{d}T} + (T_1 - T_2)\Delta S(T_1) - T_2 \int_{T_1}^{T_2}{\frac{\Delta C_\mathrm{p}(T)}{T}\mathrm{d}T}$$

For $\Delta C_\mathrm{p}$ constant with $T$:

$$\Delta G(T_2) - \Delta G(T_1) = \Delta C_\mathrm{p}(T_2 - T_1 ) + (T_1 - T_2)\Delta S(T_1) - T_2 \Delta C_\mathrm{p} \ln{\frac{T_2}{T_1}} = \\ (\Delta C_\mathrm{p} - \Delta S(T_1))(T_2 - T_1 )  - T_2 \Delta C_\mathrm{p} \ln{\frac{T_2}{T_1}}$$